# MySQL Workbench connect to MS Access

Tags: mysql, database-design, ms-access

I have a .mdb file on my computer that I would like to convert into a MySQL Schema and I have found that there is a migration tool within Workbench. However it doesn't seem to allow you to connect to a .mdb instead it looks for a server. How should I either link to my file or host my file easily as I have not done this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL Workbench to connect and migrate your schema/data from MS Access to mySQL.
First you need to configure an ODBC Data Source:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. In the Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools.
3. In the Administrative Tools dialog box, double-click Data Sources (ODBC). The ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog box appears.
4. Click User DSN, System DSN, or File DSN, depending on the type of data source you want to add. Click Add.
5. Select the driver that you want to use, and then click Finish or Next.
6. Follow the instructions and enter the required connection information in any dialog boxes that follow.

Back on MySQL Workbench: Use the menu `Database > Migrate` and select the ODBC data source you've created to use as source for your job.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement the response @marcelo-rodrigo, you can use Workbench or another tool but you will need to export table relations too (Workbench and other tools doesn't exports relations)

I write a code to extract all table relations from MS-Access database as SQL and run it on MySQL after export. [Link to Code](https://gist.github.com/ivancp/9655326) at Github Gist.

See: [Converting MS Access to MySQL with relationships](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/ms-access-to-mysql-with-relationships/)